# Camera position based on model size?

Tags: c#, wpf, camera

in C# WPF how to **automatically** set **camera** **Position** based on **3DModel** **size**.

For example if I load small model,position be closer and if I load large model camera position be longer.

What I thought was to get the **Max** and **Min** `Point3D` from model from each side.

-Find Max and Min point3D by X value.

-Find Max and Min point3D by Y value.

this is done by `foreach` loop through all 3D points.

Now I have 4 points at the edges, but how to calculate camera position?

Is there any formula to get the right position and the add some additional length to position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All depends on the framework / library you're using, but I'd guess you'd have to use the camera's FOV to calculate how wide and high the camera can 'see' at a certain distance.

[image: Camera]

If you look at the schematic of the camera, the FOV is the angle at which the camera sees stuff. It is probably a member variable of your Camera object. Splitting the triangle in two will give you two right triangles with a know angle ( 1/2 FOV ). Basic mathematics should let you calculate the distance and size of the viewwindow.

Since you already have 4 points you already know how big 'L' (in the schematic) should be.

Comment: .Net 4.5 , how to set field of view ? its behavior is more like zoom. i really dont know how it works, btw how to calculate that?